# How do I get rid of the blue focus rectangle of a flash component?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I burnt so much time on a costume made component which extends NumericStepper.
Adobe should be ashamed.. The flash component quality is poor.

Now I'm at stage that all I try to do is to disable the numericStepper's focus rectangle.

I haven't found a thing that works, all of the solutions I came across were Flex related.
To clarify : this is a pure flash ac3 project.. no flex involved.

I've tried to mess with all the component's Focus related properties and functions with no result.

Thank you very much,
Mike

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
setStyle("focusAlpha", 0); //ActionScript
focusAlpha="0"             //MXML
```

Comment: I have tried the setStyle... it just doesn't work ! with no parameter.
it compiles .. but doesn't work.. the f***** rectangle is still there.
Plus, I need to remove it completely.. so it won't catch more width and height when it appears.

Comment: Now I tried to create a new test project with the regular numeric stepper and do the setStyle line.. copy pasted it. doesn't work :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice "no flex" warning... For flash stepper, there is style focusRectSkin, set to class 'focusRectSkin' by default. Try set it to "", it should hide it.

Comment: The next line solved it :
setStyle("focusRectSkin", new Sprite());
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Also another way `focusThickness="0"`

Answer (score -1):

Try using:

```
focusRect = false;
```

in your class' constructor.